# Merge two files adding values of columns

Tags: linux, join, awk

How can I merge multiple files, of the same format, adding the values of specific columns while keeping others fixed?

If the columns of my files are of the format(where there are multiple rows):

```
File 1:
a1 b1 c1 d1 e1

File 2:
a2 b2 c2 d2 e2

File n:
an bn cn dn en

where a1=a2=an, b1=b2=bn
```

```
Output:
a b (c1+c2+...cn) (d1+d2+...dn) (e1+e2+...en)

For example,

File 1:
1 0 200 5 50
2 1 345 9 22
3 2 287 4 33

File 2:
1 0 355 4 12
2 1 366 5 7
3 2 202 7 16

I want the Output:
1 0 555 9 62
2 1 711 14 29
3 2 489 11 49
```

Comment: `awk` and friends come to mind ...

Answer (score 1):

awk-oneliner:

```
awk '{i=$1" "$2;a[i]+=$3;b[i]+=$4;c[i]+=$5}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x],b[x],c[x]}' file*
```

**test with 3 files (the oneliner works with n files)**

```
kent$  head file*
==> file1 <==
1 0 200 5 50
2 1 345 9 22
3 2 287 4 33

==> file2 <==
1 0 355 4 12
2 1 366 5 7
3 2 202 7 16

==> file3 <==
1 0 30 41 120
2 1 306 15 70
3 2 230 7 20

kent$  awk '{i=$1" "$2;a[i]+=$3;b[i]+=$4;c[i]+=$5}END{for(x in a)print x, a[x],b[x],c[x]}' file*
1 0 585 50 182
2 1 1017 29 99
3 2 719 18 69
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{getline x <f; split(x,a," ");$3+=a[3];$4+=a[4];$5+=a[5]}1' f="file1" file2
1 0 555 9 62
2 1 711 14 29
3 2 489 11 49
```

Using getline, you can parallely read the content of the other line as well. Once we split the second files content as well, it can be summed up.

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution of what [Guru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1684868/guru) gave but generalised for **n** files:

Assuming following input files:

```
==> file1 <==
1 0 200 5 50
2 1 345 9 22
3 2 287 4 33

==> file2 <==
1 0 355 4 12
2 1 366 5 7
3 2 202 7 16

==> file3 <==
1 0 400 6 14
2 1 500 5 7
3 2 202 7 16
```

Run this `awk` script:

```
awk '
    FNR < NR { 
        exit; 
    } 
    {
        for ( i = ARGC - 1; ARGV[i] != FILENAME; i-- ) {
            getline line < ARGV[i];
            r = split( line, fields );
            if ( r < 3 ) {
                continue;
            }
            if ( $1 == fields[1] && $2 == fields[2] ) {
                for ( j = 3; j <= NF; j++ ) {
                    $j += fields[j];
                }
            }
        }
        print;
    }
' file[123]
```

That yields:

```
1 0 955 15 76
2 1 1211 19 36
3 2 691 18 65
```